# MySQL Database Setup for Multiple Services

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am starting a new business that offers around 30 different services. I am trying to figure out the best way to have "easy access" to all 30 services using MySQL & PHP. At this point, I am setting up my database and I want to make sure I am going in the right direction. This is the concept I have come up with so far:

```
Create Table customers (customer_id)
Create Table orders (order_id, customer_id, product_id)
Create Table logo_design (logo_id, customer_id, order_id, product_id)
Create Table web_design (web_id, customer_id, order_id, product_id)
```

So my thought is that for each new customer, they will be assigned a unique customer ID. This ID will stay with them for each service they purchase. Where I am having a hard time is that say a customer orders 3 different services. How do I display the 3 services they have purchased without having to do a million different loops or validation checks? Really what is the best way to connect all tables for easy access?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you creating separate tables for each service when they have the same basic column? Why not have one table with a "type" column? That will simplify this immensely.

Comment: @Ilion, the reason is because each service will have different information stored in it so I thought it would be best to have separate tables for each service. The example I gave in my post was just the way of connecting all of the tables. There will be much more info stored in each table other than what I showed. Am I missing something you said though?

Comment: I don't think so, but it's hard to advise you on your structure when what you provide is not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're looking to join the tables and filter by a certain customer ID. Take a look at this example to get you started:

```
SELECT *
FROM   customers AS c
       INNER JOIN orders AS o
           ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
WHERE c.customer_id = CustomerIDGoesHere
```

You can join on to as many tables as you like

```
FROM table1
     JOIN table2
         ON table1.column = table2.column
     JOIN table3
         ON table2.column = table3.column
     JOIN table4
         ON table1.column = table4.column
```

Comment: Okay, I understand. So say I wanted to pull all orders for the customer_id 10. And say for some reason this customer has ordered all 30 services. Would I have to JOIN all 30 tables?

Comment: No, all 30 rows from the order table which has the customer id would be displayed, along with any information from the customer table. You only have to join the tables once and specify what data you want. In this case you are saying that you want to join the customers and the orders and display all the rows for a particular customer ID. Try putting some data into your tables and playing about a bit

Comment: Thank you for the sample!...Now say I want to retrive information from the 3 orders. Say I want to get the first & last name of entered for product_id 2. How would I do this after selecting all rows from the orders table associated with a certain customer_id?

Comment: Updated example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ad3f/12 shows how to select specific columns from joined tables

Answer (score 0):

relational databases usually have a table in between a table like customer and a table like services. call it customer_ordered_services maybe

and it just holds a key to the customer and the service they want

in your example there would be three rows in this middle table to reflect the three services they want

```
customerId 1, serviceId 1
customerId 1, serviceId 2
customerId 1, serviceId 3
```

Comment: The customer_ordered_services table is the same as my orders table correct?

Comment: yes, if product_id links to logo_id or web_id. im not sure why product_id is in those tables